# Find a function $f(x)$ so that the graph of $y=f(x)$ is the path of the particle.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

The equation $r(t) = \frac{t}{t+4} \vec i + \frac{4}{t} \vec j$ gives the position of a particle in the $xy$-plane at time $t$.

Find a function $f(x)$ so that the graph of $y=f(x)$ is the path of the particle. Then find the particle's velocity and acceleration vectors at time $t=\frac{1}{10}$.

So I found the velocity to be $\frac {400}{1681}\vec i - 400 \vec j $ and the acceleration to be $\frac {8000}{68921}\vec i+8000 \vec j$.

But I am so confused on how to do the first part of the problem? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hint: The graph is given by $x \vec i + f(x) \vec j$. So in your case $x = \frac{t}{t+4}$. So what is $t$ expressed in terms of $x$?

Comment: is it x? sorry, but how do i move these variables around? i already have all the t's on one side.sorry if this is a stupid question. @John

Comment: ok so i did this x(t+4)=t. but now what do i do.

Comment: @Elsa Solve for $t$.

Comment: @Bye_World ya that is what im trying to do. how do i move all the t's to one side?

Comment: Like this $x(t+4)=t \implies xt+4x=t \implies xt-t=-4x \implies t(x-1)=-4x \implies t= \dfrac{4x}{1-x}$.

Comment: @Bye_World omg ya i was just doing that! srry for the brainfart!

Comment: @John so i found it in t in terms of x. is that the path of the particle? it says to do this y = ____

Comment: Now $f(x) = \frac{4}{t} = $ (in terms of $x$, then you found $f(x)$)

Comment: @John why should I move the 4 over? and how come that is f(x) when f(x) is supposed to be y=______? because this is just t = ______. Oh wait did i misinterpret ur comment wrong?

Comment: @John currently right now i have $\frac{4x}{1-x}$=t. Do you mean to do $\frac{4x}{1-x}$=$\frac{4}{t}$ because $\frac{4}{t}j$?

Comment: So can you write $\frac 4t $ in terms of $x$? If yes, then that's $f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on here: $\mathbf r(t) = \frac{t}{t+4} \mathbf i + \frac{4}{t} \mathbf j$ is a curve in the plane.  Can you see this?

This is a vector equation.  However, remembering high school algebra, we know that we can represent curves in the plane as $y=f(x)$ (assuming the curve *is* representable as a function $x$ -- not every curve in the plane is).  So what the first part of this question is asking is for you to find the *scalar* equation $y=f(x)$ that corresponds to exactly the same curve as $\mathbf r(t)$.

But remember also that $\mathbf r(t) = \frac{t}{t+4} \mathbf i + \frac{4}{t} \mathbf j$ can also be written as 
$$\mathbf r(t) = \pmatrix{x(t) \\ y(t)} = \pmatrix {\frac{t}{t+4} \\ \frac{4}{t}}$$

So $y=\frac 4t$.  But we don't want $y$ expressed as a function of $t$, we want it expressed as a function of $x$.  So we use the relationship we know between $x$ and $t$: $x=\frac{t}{t+4}$, solve it for $t$, and then plug that expression into the $t$ in the equation $y=\frac 4t$.  Then you'll have $y$ expressed solely as a function of $x$ and thus you'll be done.

A little bit of algebra shows us that $t= \frac {4x}{1-x}$, so clearly $$\color{red}{y} = \frac 4t = \frac {4(1-x)}{4x} = \color{red}{\frac {1-x}{x}}$$

Comment: ohhhhh I get it! so Im plugging in $\frac{4x}{1-x}$ in the t in $\frac {4}{t}$! ohhh ya i get that part about the three equations in the vector. thank u!